# Входные данные к реализации алгоритма Куна

Tags: алгоритм, графы, дискретная-математика

Хочу изучить и реализовать Венгерский алгоритм (задача о назначениях). Как я понимаю, алгоритм Куна является его составной частью (решает промежуточную задачу поиска максимального паросочетания). Код, найденный мной по ссылке, компилируется, но ввод матрицы "как есть" приводит к аварийному завершению программы. Требуется ли в данном случае какой-то особый формат входных данных? Если да, то как привести к нему матрицу (где показана связь между работниками и заданиями)?

https://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching

Comment: В пункте "Реализация" описано, в каком виде нужно хранить граф: "g[v] — список рёбер из вершины v первой доли (т.е. список номеров вершин, в которые ведут эти рёбра из v).". Если у вас есть матрица смежности, то чтобы привести ее к данному виду вам нужно для каждого работника v записать в вектор g[v] все такие задания u, что matr[v][u] = 1.

Comment: Приведи, пожалуйста, пример входных данных

Comment: Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что по венгерскому алгоритму почитать. Я даже не понимаю, где нужно искать максимальное паросочетание...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/n9ES5suQ

Comment: Я лично никогда его не писал, но вообще первых четырех ссылок из гугла с большей вероятностью хватит для любых нужд:
https://e-maxx.ru/algo/assignment_hungary
https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Венгерский_алгоритм_решения_задачи_о_назначениях
https://habr.com/ru/post/422009/
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Венгерский_алгоритм

Comment: В исходной матрице числа вроде могут быть любые положительные. Или считать их все единицами?

Comment: В алгоритме Куна - да, единицами. Он работает с невзвешенными двудольными графами, так что просто если есть ребро, то единица, если нет, то ноль

Comment: Позволит ли алгоритм Куна сразу получить максимальное паросочетание из ребер с нулевым весом (как требует венгерский алгоритм) или там модификации нужны?

Comment: Как я и сказал парой сообщений выше - я никогда его не писал и не могу утверждать что-то наверняка. Если алгоритм Куна используется в Венгерском алгоритме, значит либо он работает и так, либо в описании Венгерского алгоритма упомянуты нужные модификации.

Comment: Список смежности, который вы привели, описывает ориентированный граф (из левой доли в правую)?

Comment: В принципе да, можно считать его ориентированным.

Comment: Спасибо! P.S. Теперь хочу теорему Кёнига применить для поиска минимального вершинного покрытия. Для этого нужно ориентировать часть ребер в одну сторону, а часть в другую. Не подскажешь, в каком виде тогда лучше хранить матрицу (чтобы не разводить кучу разных структур данных)?

Comment: Вообще, что мне потом нужно сделать со списком смежности, чтобы ребра из паросочетания ориентировать из правой доли в левую, а не из паросочетания - наоборот?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116416/discussion-between-ezikbro-and-maxim-voloshin).